# Remove numpy array of False/True from image numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array of an image

```
img = [[[63  48  27]
  [ 63  48  27]
  [ 63  48  27]
  ...
  [117  88  70]
  [113  84  66]
  [111  82  64]]

 [[ 64  49  28]
  [ 64  49  28]
  [ 64  49  28]
  ...
  [117  88  70]
  [114  85  67]
  [111  82  64]]

 [[ 65  50  29]
  [ 66  51  30]
  [ 66  51  30]
  ...
  [118  89  71]
  [114  85  67]
  [111  82  64]]...
```

And another array of the pixels that I want to keep from that image array:

```
mask = [[[False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  ...
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]
  [False False False ... False False False]]]
```

I thought I could just do `img[mask]` but I get `boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 549 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1`. How can I either expand the mask array back to the right dimension, it comes from converting a detectron2 mask to numpy array `mask = outputs['instances'].pred_masks.numpy()` (originally it's a tensor). Or, and this could be easier I think, if the value in the numpy mask array is `False` then convert the  element in the image array to white/255.

The function I'm using is:

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
import scipy.misc


def cropper(org_image_path, mask_array, out_file_name):
    img = imread(org_image_path)
    output = img[mask_array]
    scipy.misc.toimage(output).save(out_file_name)
```

Comment: can you print out their shapes?

Comment: img.shape = (549, 440, 3)
mask_array.shape = (1, 549, 440)

Comment: Would you like to know how to apply that mask to that image?

Comment: @alan.elkin no thanks, I can already apply the mask to the image but I'm trying to return just the masked area of the image (without the mask)

Comment: From Nicolas' comment, I'm guessing I can somehow reshape the mask array with .reshape but not clear on how

Comment: That's what "apply" means

Comment: Please provide an MCVE. If your mask is an irregular shape, how do you expect to get a rectangular array out?

Comment: I don't expect to get a rectangular cut out, I expect to get the mask array. If the mask array element value is False set the image array values to 255, if it's True leave as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, Nicholas' comment was a useful bump (thank you) - just changed the mask array to be on the same axis & the same shape. Then was just a simple edit to change the values:

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
import scipy.misc
from PIL import Image  

def cropper(org_image_path, mask_array, out_file_name):
        img = imread(org_image_path)
        mask_array = np.moveaxis(mask_array, 0, -1)
        mask_array = np.repeat(mask_array, 3, axis=2)
        output = np.where(mask_array==False, 255, img)
        im = Image.fromarray(output)
        im.save(out_file_name)
```

Comment: This is not at all what your question is asking

Comment: Please explain how it isn't? Given that I wrote the question I do know the output I need.

Comment: I'm sure it is, in which case you may want to consider deleting the question. I'm merely saying that the question you wrote down does not correspond to the answer. SO is all about future readers. If you update the question according to site rules, that's a whole different matter.

Comment: In what way does it not correspond to the question?

Comment: I didn't see your updates on mobile. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Given an image of shape `(M, N, 3)` and a mask of shape `(1, M, N)`, you can set the `False` elements of the image to 255 in all channels by using simple boolean indexing. Whereas broadcasting lines up indices on the right, indexing fills them in on the left. That means that to get the mask to correspond to your image dimensions you need to remove the first axis. There are a number of ways of doing this:

```
mask = mask[0]
mask = mask[0, ...]
mask = mask.squeeze()
mask = np.squeeze(mask)
mask = mask.reshape(mask.shape[1:])
mask = np.reshape(mask, mask.shape[1:])
...
```

With the first two dimensions matching up, you can negate the mask and preform a direct assignment:

```
img[~mask] = 255
```

This can be combined into a simple one-liner:

```
img[~mask[0]] = 255
```